# How do I change price after X years?

Tags: civimember

I'm setting up a Civi install and i'm wondering how to go about these requirements:

- Residents who join in their first year pay $40 for the duration of their graduate medical training program. Residents who are in their 2nd or last year of their training program pay $20 each year.
- Medical students who join in their first year pay $20 for the duration of their undergraduate medical training program. Students who are in their 2nd or last year of their training program pay $10 each year.

Can we dynamically change the membership amount somehow?

Thanks

Comment: Does the system know the status of first, 2nd or last year of a contact? Or does the person indicate that at the time of membership?

Comment: Most likely option #1 as we have the membership start dates

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little unclear about the requirements, but if the status of a contact's year is known then perhaps you can use CiviDiscount.

Automatic discounts can be applied to existing members and contact types.